# Enable secure playback, Widevine DRM in python webbrowsers (Protected content)

Tags: python, webview, pyqt5, widevine

I'm trying to use the spotify web player on a python browser windows.

I try it in two ways:

```py
import webview
webview.create_window('spotify', 'https://open.spotify.com')
webview.start()
```

```py
import sys
import time

from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web = QWebEngineView()
web.load(QUrl("https://open.spotify.com/"))
web.showFullScreen()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

After I log in with my account I get:

> Enable secure playback in your browser.

Is there way I can do this? In the spotify support page it tells me to enable protected content playback or play drm. I am not sure if it is possible.

Comment: You may need to define some environment variable as [documented](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-features.html#html5-drm), and use Qt 5.7.0 or later.

Comment: You can probably move that additional edit to a self-answer. Also, you're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By @metatoaster 's suggestion, I tried to set the `QTWEBENGINE_CHROMIUM_FLAGS` environment variable to `--widevine-path="/home/<myusername>/.mozilla/firefox/237oaqbb.default-release/gmp-widevinecdm/4.10.2449.0/libwidevinecdm.so"`

After I got the location from `locate libwidevinecdm.so`, and it worked!

I tried with the spotify's path for the library but that didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean with the last paragraph? What library?

Comment: @musicamante I mean widevinecdm, mozilla and spotify comes with it but when I pointed the env variable to the one located in spotify's directory, it didn't work. Mozilla's did though.

Comment: And why would you use the spotify one? Even when using the spotify web player, it uses the *browser's* library, certainly not the app one, which could be custom-built or just obsolete for newer online services (they only use it for *their* standalone player). Just use the mozilla one if it works, using the other is pointless.

Comment: @musicamante Yeah, that's what I'm using. What's your point?

Comment: I'm asking you what's *yours* :-) If you need to use widevine for web browsing, you need the most up-to-date version used for a browser, since you may use different sources that might require higher level of protection (or even a specific minimum version of the library). Programs that use it specifically for *their* content might not need that level of DRM control "update", since they have direct control over the content that they play.